# Convert copied text to hyperlinked-formatted text

Tags: autohotkey

this is either a really stupid, easy question or a tricky one. For the life of me, I cannot figure it out. I do a regular copy/pasting website urls for my job which need to be hyperlinked. Sometimes I copy links from a notepad and sometimes directly from the address bar of a browser. When copying a website URL from an internet browser address bar, it is copied and pasted as hyperlinked text when I paste somewhere (such as an email, Grammarly, etc) > this is what I want.

When copying from my notepad archives of URLs, it pastes the URL as plain text, and I have to manually hyperlink it. I'd love to automate this in some way. I wish it were as simple as adding html tags but I haven't had any luck.

So I'm reaching out to you guys to see if you have luck doing this same task.

Answer (score 0):

These few lines helped me tremendously: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=62907

Here is my resulting script.

```
F3:: ;Change this hotkey to what you want

; copy text
; if https* 
;   >paste as html formatted hyperlink
;   >else; paste untouched

If InStr(Clipboard, "https://")=1
  {
    ;Clipboard contents starts with https:// routed here.
      text1 := "<a href="
      text2 := """"
      text3 := Clipboard
      text4 := """"
      text5 := ">"
      text6 := Clipboard
      text7 := "</a>"
      fullStr := text1 . text2 . text3 . text4 . text5 . text6 . text7
      ;MsgBox % fullStr ;String check.
      WinClip.Clear()
      ;WinClip.SetText("www.ahkscript.org") ;not sure I ever need this for my purposes.
      WinClip.SetHTML(fullStr)
      WinClip.Paste()
      return
  } Else {
    ;Clipboard contents does not start w/ https:// routed here.
    Send, ^v
  }
#Include C:\PathToWinClip\WinClipAPI.ahk
#Include C:\PathToWinClip\WinClip.ahk
```

Comment: You should use a regexmatch rather than `instr(clipboard, "https://")` which would be like `RegExMatch(clipboard, "https?:\/\/")`